# Is it possible to use cogroup + applyInPandas for more than 2 pyspark dataframes as input?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

As mentioned in the [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.PandasCogroupedOps.applyInPandas.html), the function to be applied by `applyInPandas` takes two pandas.DataFrames and returns one another pandas.DataFrame. Hence the following can be done:

```py
def function_with_two_args(pdf1, pdf2):
    result_pdf = <do this and that>
    return result_pdf
df1.groupby("id").cogroup(df2.groupby("id")).applyInPandas(
    function_with_two_args, schema="time int, id int, v1 double, v2 string"
)
```

Is there any way to use similar techniques but with more than 2 pandas df inputs, so similarly:

```py
def function_with_two_args(pdf1, pdf2, pdf3, pdf4):
    result_pdf = <do this and that>
    return result_pdf

df1.groupby("id")
.cogroup(df2.groupby("id"))
.cogroup(df3.groupby("id"))
.cogroup(df4.groupby("id"))
.applyInPandas(
    function_with_two_args, schema="time int, id int, v1 double, v2 string"
)
```

Above does not work currently for pyspark 3.2.0, since it is not possible to do another `cogroup` after one. Any suggestions how to make above works?

```py
def function_with_two_args(pdf1, pdf2, pdf3, pdf4):
    result_pdf = <do this and that>
    return result_pdf

df1.groupby("id")
.cogroup(df2.groupby("id"))
.cogroup(df3.groupby("id"))
.cogroup(df4.groupby("id"))
.applyInPandas(
    function_with_two_args, schema="time int, id int, v1 double, v2 string"
)
```

resulted in `AttributeError: 'PandasCogroupedOps' object has no attribute 'cogroup'`

Answer (score 1):

Pandas UDF doesn't support cogroup with multiple dataframes. As a workaround, you could:

```py
df1.groupby("id")
.cogroup(df2.groupby("id"))
.applyInPandas(...)
.groupby("id")
.cogroup(df3.groupby("id"))
.applyInPandas(...)
.groupby("id")
.cogroup(df4.groupby("id"))
.applyInPandas(...)
```

That said, this is a very useful feature to have in spark. RDDs already support cogroup with multiple RDDs. We should open a JIRA.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Let's create a spark jira ticket.